# How to configure my app with capability "PrivateNetworkClientServer" and keep possibility to pass "WACK" test

Tags: apache-cordova, local-network, wack

I am working on  Apache Cordova Win 10 Windows-x86 Store app for the data exchanging with the  microcomputers collecting measurements, connected entirely to a local network.

I tested this app  with capability "PrivateNetworkClientServer"  and
deployed it in a form of "*.appx" package.  It is working.

But  "PrivateNetworkClientServer" capability is forbidden for Windows Store
with the setting in "package.windows10.appxmanifest" as this:

`"uap:Rule Match="ms-appx-web:///" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" "`

I have tried to change this setting or remove it (by default WindowsRuntimeAccess="none"),
but after running "build" this part of manifest was returned to its initial state.

[image]

How to configure my app with capability "PrivateNetworkClientServer" and keep
possibility to pass "WACK" test.

I  appreciate any suggestions.
Thank you.

Comment: I still have the same problem, so i have to choose between having a win store cert or access to web API in the local network. At least it works with localhost and external APIs

Answer (score 0):

To have access from my Win Store App to web API in the local network I am using the "Fiddler4" exemption for now, but still hope to find more simple solution. The same Cordova app, but built with Visual Studio for Android, works in the same local network without any quirks.

Comment: does this allow you to connect to other computers in the same network, like 192.168.1.12 for example? Because the exempt only allows me to reach my own IP (localhost). I'm adding my exempt with powershell script `Invoke-Expression ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("System")+"\CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n='my-app-family-name'");`